# Refresh information in tab WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I am a beginner automation tester.
I am testing WPF application with `CodedUITest`.

I have big problem. I need to refresh information in a tab. Not in a control, but in a tab.

For example:
I have a popup and a button.
When I choose value in popup, and after try clicking button, the test fails with `ElementNotAvailableException`.
If I click on button before choosing the popup - all right.
Sometimes tests fail with this exception, but sometimes they succeed.

This problem started after developers made replacing templates in the grid, and they said that it is not a problem WPF(Xaml), but I need to refresh tab in my tests.

I don't know how to do that.

We use search elements with `AutomationElement`.
Choose element and click button code:

```cs
internal void Choose(AutomationElement element, string value)
{
    if (NameProperty(element) != value)
    {
        Open(element);

        AutomationElement valueInPopup = FindByName(PART_ListBox(), value);

        ChooseValueInPopup(valueInPopup, value);
    }
}

private void ChooseValueInPopup(AutomationElement element, string value)
{
    AutomationElement valueInPopup = FindByName(element, value);
    LeftClickElement(valueInPopup);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

private void ClickSaveEventButton()
{
    AutomationElement saveButton = FooterSaveButton();
    LeftClickElement(saveButton);
    WaitBusyElementWithoutParameter(saveButton, BusyIndicator);
}
```

I need help. Thank you.

Comment: As I understood, you have a TabControl and tab items inside? Have you tried to use UpdateLayout() for the tab items?

Comment: I have all elements type AutomationElement.
I dont know, how use UpdateLayout for AutomationElement type ((

Comment: UpdateLayout() is a method for a tab element to update the content, so you should try to find the tab in the menu with AutomationElement, if it contains the control maybe you can access the rest of elements, including the tab.

Comment: We have old problem. Information in tab not refresh. 
Visual UI Verify dont see new elements in tab too.
Only if reopen tab. 
UI Verify have button Refresh Selected Element, but he dont see new elements again.

Comment: But if i try find new controls with Snoop, after that information in tab refresh!